# D3 sorting with an ordinal scale and selecting top 5

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I am trying to sort then select the top 5 in a D3 chart.

I have two series: "OL" and "NOL". The first thing I want to be able to do is to sort and have the labels match on the y axis. The second thing I want to do is to only show the top 5 with the two series still together udner one name in the y axis.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/p1pfhat8/)

Data is like so:

```
var values = feature.properties;              
var data = [
    {key: "N11", name:"N11OL",value:values["N11OL"]},
    {key: "N11", name:"N11NOL",value:values["N11NOL"]},
    {key: "N21", name:"N21OL",value:values["N21OL"]},
    {key: "N21", name:"N21NOL",value:values["N21NOL"]},
    {key: "N22", name:"N22OL",value:values["N22OL"]},
    {key: "N22", name:"N22NOL",value:values["N22NOL"]},
    {key: "N23", name:"N23OL",value:values["N23OL"]},
    {key: "N23", name:"N23NOL",value:values["N23NOL"]},
    {key: "N31-33", name:"N31_33OL",value:values["N31_33OL"]},
    {key: "N31-33", name:"N31_33NOL",value:values["N31_33NOL"]},
    {key: "N41", name:"N41OL",value:values["N41OL"]},
    {key: "N41", name:"N41NOL",value:values["N41NOL"]}
];
```

Right now, the chart works before I sort the bars. When I sort the data with the code below, the ordinal domain doesn't match the bars anymore.

```
   data.sort(function (a, b) {
return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value);
});
```

I could use

```
domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))`
});
```

to get the names from the data to show on the axis but I want "OL" and "NOL" series to be under one name: N11, etc. not show with all bars. That is why I have set a domain with :

```
.domain(["NAICS11", "NAICS21", "NAICS22", "NAICS23", "NAICS31-33", "NAICS41"])
```

That is half of the problem. Once I have sorted and the names are matching with the axis, I would like to have only the top 5 for both series.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how to do this.

**EDIT** I added a key to the data for the pairs and modified the D3 code. I feel this will make it easier going forward to get this chart where I want it.

Comment: I'm confused.  If `N11OL` and `N11NOL` need to stay paired, how would the sorting work?  Sort by the maximum of each pair or the sum of each pair?

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out. Maybe there is another way to structure the data? They do need to stay paired and I would like the axis to show the domain names.

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to figure you, you just have to pick a method.  I personally would use max...

Comment: How would you sort on the maximum of each pair in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
        // create temporary array with data grouped by 
        // the first part of our name (cut off the OL/NOL)
        var tmp = d3.nest().key(function(d){
            return d.name.substring(0, 3);
        }).entries(data);

        // sort this array descending with the max of our
        // now "paired" entries
        tmp.sort(function(a,b){
           return (d3.max([a.values[0].value,
                   a.values[1].value]) > 
             d3.max([b.values[0].value,
                    b.values[1].value])) ? -1 : 1;
        });

        // loop our tmp array and 
        // flatten the data back out
        // also use our substring names to for the domain
        data = [];
        domain = [];
        tmp.forEach(function(d){
            domain.push(d.key);
            data.push(d.values[0]);
            data.push(d.values[1]);
        });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1pfhat8/105/).

Comment: This works very well Mark. Could you provide more details on your solution?

Comment: Mark, thank you! This is eye opening and I have learned much from this. Now, I suspect that selecting the top 5 before drawing the chart is as simple as doing something like : data = data.slice(0,5)?

Comment: @Monduiz, you got it.